# Retrieve data more than once Oracle Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

This is my table:

```sql
create table temp (acc number, name varchar2(20), mobile number);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(123,'ABC',11111);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(456,'ABC',11111);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(789,'XYZ',22222);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(852,'XYZ',22222);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(654,'UPI',33333);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(951,'FYI',44444);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(159,'FYI',44444);
insert into temp (acc,name,mobile)values(951,'DRY',55555);
```

I need to Retrieve  data like below name and mobile number should be repeat more than once

My output

[image]

Can anyone help me to get this output

Answer (score 0):

Use the analytic `COUNT` function to find rows where there is are duplicate `name`/`moblie` pairs:

```
SELECT acc, name, mobile
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name, mobile) AS cnt
  FROM   temp t
)
WHERE  cnt > 1;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | ACC | NAME | MOBILE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 456 | ABC | 11111 |
> | 123 | ABC | 11111 |
> | 159 | FYI | 44444 |
> | 951 | FYI | 44444 |
> | 789 | XYZ | 22222 |
> | 852 | XYZ | 22222 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c960b0eec131db89d9e47d5a3ae439ce)*